# How to VBA update a cell value based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I've looked all over stack exchange and have not seen exactly what I'm looking for. I have an extensive list of some items that need constant calibration at different dates and intervals, and what I'm trying to do is make a VBA/Macro so that I can update any one specific item's calibration date with out having to look at each individual entry or using =VLOOKUP(). so far I have nothing solid I can call a program yet, but what I had envisioned was in a cell write the item's ID#, in another cell the new calibration exp date and have a button next to them so that is searches for the ID#, moves one column to the right and replace the text on the cell with the new date. Simple enough to explain but given the fact that I just started learning about VBA four hours ago, it's proving to be a challenge. So far I've toyed with some code to no avail:

`range("a1").Formula = "=CELL("address", INDEX(H:J, MATCH(L11,H:H, 0),2))"`

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(R[-5]C[-9], 3, 2, )"`

I will provide more information or context if anyone needs it!

Answer (score 0):

When using quotes inside a formula you should double up on them:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=CELL(""address"", INDEX(H:J, MATCH(L11,H:H, 0),2))"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(R[-5]C[-9], 3, 2, )"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you pretty close.  You can adjust this to fit your data.
The commented out MsgBox commands can be deleted, but are handy for debugging.

```
Sub SetCalDate()

    'Set up variables
    Dim ID, RowNum As Integer
    Dim NewCalDate As Date
    Dim IDNums As Range

    'Initialize variables
    ID = Range("A1").Value           'Assumes the ID to Find is in A1,
    NewCalDate = Range("B1").Value   'and the NewCalDate is in B1.
    'MsgBox NewCalDate
    Set IDNums = Range("C1:C10")     'This is the range of ID's to be searched.
    'You might need something like Set IDNums = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C1:C10")
    'if the ID numbers are on a different sheet.

    'Find the ID in IDNums
    RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID, IDNums, 0)
    'MsgBox RowNum
    Range("D" & RowNum) = NewCalDate    'Assumes the CalDates are in column D.

End Sub
```

If you want to assign the macro to a button, put the code in a new module first, then make a button and assign the SetCalDate() macro to it as explained [on this help page](https://peltiertech.com/how-to-assign-a-macro-to-a-button-or-shape/).  Good luck.